# Making an Interactive Map that can work with multiple resolutions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-engine

I am trying to learn Unity. I am proficient in C# however I am new with Unity. I am trying to make a game that whenever you click a country, say the USA, it will show you statistics about that country. Think of the game Plague Inc. that when you click a country it gives you statistics and this works with multiple device resolutions. I am trying to figure out how to do that, I do not know where to start or what to do. I have been on the Unity discord but I have not had much luck with this question, I would appreciate all help with this, thanks you! I have attached an image to show what I have used. I am using a Canvas for the base then I am using an Image to display the Map.[image: Unity Image]
I am also for note using Unity2d

Answer (score 0):

Using Unity UI you can set anchor points and specify percentages of the screen instead of specific pixels, so it will scale depending on the resolution each machine has. Was this your question?

Comment: Kinda, I understand that but if I was to make an interactive map like I described above, I am unsure how to do that and from what I have read online, it wouldn't work with different resolutions. I tried to help it with bringing in the game Plague Inc. for mobile devices on how the game works with their map for multiple resolutions. I am wanting to achieve that characteristic but I am unsure how to.